# SharePoint 2010 FBA Authentication Sequence - Behind the screen

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, authentication, forms-authentication, architecture, membership-provider

I am new to SharePoint world and we are in process of implementing the FBA in SharePoint 2010 and it is working as we have followed some articles from net.

Now I wanted to understand how does the authentication process flow happen behind the scene?

Ex: When a user is created it saved in ASPNET membership DB and the User Roles are saved inside the SharePoint Group. Now when the user try to login and the login request goes to SharePoint then how does SharePoint authenticate the user? I wanted to know the internal flow or sequence. Any pointer will be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete explanation is difficult here.

So pls refer to this link [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/05/27/understanding-sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @Pushpendra for the pointer. That links is very easy to understand.